SQL Server 2019 failed to Start after Hot Patch upgrade
We have 2019 SQL Servers and I was able to upgrade Patch without any issues except 1.
After Patch upgrade, it fails to start.

Script level upgrade for database 'master' failed because upgrade step 'ISServer_upgrade.sql' encountered error 3602, state 251, severity 25. This is a serious error condition which might interfere with regular operation and the database will be taken offline. If the error happened during upgrade of the 'master' database, it will prevent the entire SQL Server instance from starting. Examine the previous errorlog entries for errors, take the appropriate corrective actions and re-start the database so that the script upgrade steps run to completion.

I can start SQL using this command
NET START MSSQLSERVER /T902

It shows SSISDB in Single User Mode. Shows below

In one of the form they ##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobUser## is missing. So needs to be created. But I do have that user available.
When I start, I get 3 errors in Event Log.

SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect pageid (expected 1:3088; actual 0:0). It occurred during a read of page (1:3088) in database ID 7 at offset 0x00000001820000 in file '...\MSSQL\DATA\SSISDB.mdf'.  Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or operating system error log may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2252374.

Script level upgrade for database 'master' failed because upgrade step 'ISServer_upgrade.sql' encountered error 3602, state 251, severity 25. This is a serious error condition which might interfere with regular operation and the database will be taken offline. If the error happened during upgrade of the 'master' database, it will prevent the entire SQL Server instance from starting. Examine the previous errorlog entries for errors, take the appropriate corrective actions and re-start the database so that the script upgrade steps run to completion.

Cannot recover the master database. SQL Server is unable to run. Restore master from a full backup, repair it, or rebuild it. For more information about how to rebuild the master database, see SQL Server Books Online.


I have backup of user databases, but for System databases I have only mdf and ldf backups.
I copied the mdf and ldf files from backup for master and SSISDB and it still didn't work.
Also checked the Region Settings, to see if Beta use Unicode UTF-8 is checked and didn't see that got checked.

All other database got upgraded fine without any hicup. I see this server also upgraded and I can see the version 15.0.4365.2 shows up except SSISDB.
Any help to start the database without /T902?

Finally Figured this Out.
Based on Errorlog, I saw some Consistency Errors in SSISDB.
So i ran DBCC CHECK and it showed to use REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS is the minimum i can use. So Ran it with the DBCC Check with REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS and it fixed the database. After that Restarted the database and it worked like charm.

REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS is very risky. A backup or a rebuild would have been better.

Are you running Checkdb frequently ? was a CheckDB done before the upgrade ?  P.s. It is highly recommanded to have checkdb running on your databases at regular interval (1 day, 1 week, etc... depending on your organisation)

Restored backup from mdf file and after restore also gave same error. This was vendor provided database and looks like no DBCC checks on weekly basis. Its now scheduled to run DBCC Check weekly basis now. I handle other databases for our application and we do have DBCC checks weekly.  I was looped in to upgrade Hot Patch and next time i will check before Patching.
